# Can filter manipulate elements before returning them in a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array of strings like so:

```
var someArray = ['this is something', 'this is something else', "this ain't something"];
```

And I want to filter them by which strings start with `this is` while also getting rid of `this is` in the filtered array. I'm currently doing that by writing:

```
var newArray = [];
for (var index = 0; index < someArray.length; index++) {
  if (someArray [index].startsWith ("this is ")) {
    newArray.push (someArray [index].slice (8));
  }
}
```

Another way I can do it is by writing something like:

```
function filterByThisIs (arrayElement) {
  return arrayElement.startsWith ("this is ");
}
function removeThisIs (arrayElement, index, someOtherArray) {
  someOtherArray [index] = arrayElement.slice (8);
}
var newArray = someArray.filter (filterByThisIs).forEach (removeThisIs);
```

Now, maybe it's just because I'm new to JavaScript and just recently discovered `array.filter()`, but I feel like `array.filter()` SHOULD be able to do something like that without the help of `array.forEach()`since it also accepts a function argument anyway. Can `array.filter()` somehow just manipulate the elements for me while it's filtering them into the new array? Or is there some other easier and cleaner way than the above that I'm not thinking of maybe?

Comment: filters just filter, depending whether callback function returns truly or falsy values. if you want to manipulate output data then search for `reduce`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reduce`:

```
var newArray = someArray.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (!c.startsWith("this is ")) return a;
  a.push(c.slice(8));
  return a;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can Array.filter() manipulate elements before returning them in a new array?

No, it doesn't manipulate elements. It just returns a new array with elements which pass a condition.

But there are many ways to do what you want. One approach is to use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in combination with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var someArray = ['this is something', 'this is something else', "this ain't something"];
    
// Filter array items which start with "this is ".
var filteredArray = someArray.filter(element => element.startsWith("this is "));
    
// Trim "this is " from each item.
var outputArray = filteredArray.map(element => element.slice(8));
  
console.log(outputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, there are many methods to achieve this, here is how I do it,

```
var someArray = ['this is something', 'this is something else', "this ain't something"];

// First filter item and then slice that text on returning item
var newArray = someArray
                    .filter(item => item.startsWith("this is "))
                    .map(item => item.slice(8));


console.log(newArray);
```